# Get file name & destination of VBA save dialog box

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have set up a dialog box which will allow a user to pick a file destination. After the destination is picked, you can input a name of the file, and will set "FileSaveName" to the full path  like  `C:\user\desktop\test.xml` I am new to this tool that is offered through VBA. Is it possible to obtain the file name and the extension separately? Or will I need to manually trim characters from the string?

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xml), *.xml")
If fileSaveName <> False Then
    MsgBox "File path and file name: " & fileSaveName
    'MsgBox "File path: " & filepath
    'MsgBox "File name: " & filename
End If
```

Comment: See this thread. http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/3/2/retrieving-the-file-name-extension-from-a-file-path-string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Scripting objects:

```
Dim objFS   as Object
Dim objFile as Object
Dim strPath as String
Dim strFile as String
Dim strExt  as String


fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xml), *.xml")
If fileSaveName <> False Then
    MsgBox "File path and file name: " & fileSaveName

    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileSaveName)

    strFile = objFile.Name
    strPath = objFile.ParentFolder 
    strExt = objFS.GetExtensionName(fileSaveName)

    MsgBox "File path: " & strPath
    MsgBox "File name: " & strFile
    MsgBox "File extension: " & strExt

    ' Remove references
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFS = Nothing


End If
```

[Good reference here](https://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this

```
Sub main()
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xml), *.xml")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
        MsgBox "File path and file name: " & fileSaveName
        MsgBox "File path: " & GetFilePath(fileSaveName)
        MsgBox "File name: " & GetFileName(fileSaveName)
        MsgBox "File extension: " & GetFileExt(fileSaveName)
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFilePath(fileFullPath As Variant) As String
    GetFilePath = Left(fileFullPath, InStrRev(fileFullPath, "\"))
End Function

Function GetFileName(fileFullPath As Variant) As String
    GetFileName = Right(fileFullPath, Len(fileFullPath) - InStrRev(fileFullPath, "\"))
End Function

Function GetFileExt(fileFullPath As Variant) As String
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = GetFileName(fileFullPath)
    GetFileExt = Right(fileName, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "."))
End Function
```